# iptables-restore sometimes fails on reboot

Tags: linux, iptables, systemd

Today and yesterday, my server automatically rebooted and failed to bring up the network device during boot. If I reboot the machine again, then it starts up fine, I've also not encountered any issues with this during the past 2 months.

The only error logs I can find relating to this are:

```
Aug 23 06:37:14 server systemd[1]: Started ifup for ens16.
Aug 23 06:37:14 server systemd[1]: ifup@ens16.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

and

```
Aug 23 06:37:14 server sh[281]: iptables-restore: line 10 failed
Aug 23 06:37:14 server systemd[1]: ifup@ens16.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 06:37:14 server sh[281]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables exited with return code 1
Aug 23 06:37:14 server sh[281]: ifup: failed to bring up ens16
```

`/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

`/etc/iptables.up.rules` contains:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [896:90530]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

What could possibly be going wrong with this in an intermittent fashion, and how can I make sure it doesn't happen again?

Comment: Start by saving the output of `/sbin/iptables-restore` to a file and see what messages it contains.

Comment: Finally happened again. There was no message. The file is empty, after having changed the command to `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules > /var/log/iptables-output`.

Comment: Try `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules >& /var/log/iptables-output` - ifthere's an error, it's likely to appear on STDERR.  NB if your `sh` is really `sh`, not `bash`, modify accordingly.

Comment: What Linux distribution is this?

Comment: @MadHatter Assumed stderr is what was already in the error logs shown above. But, will try that out.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Debian stable.

Comment: @MadHatter I would modify that command to include the PID in the file name like this: `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules >& /var/log/iptables-output.$$`. I have a suspicion that script gets executed more than once during boot, it would be nice to have the output from all the invocations.

Comment: try appending instead of overwriting... i.e. restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules 2>&1 >> /var/log/iptables-output.$$

Comment: @SamBull Please, could you provide output of command `systemctl list-units --all 'ifup*.service'`? I believe the network interface fails to start due to a concurrent execution of your `iptables` script.

Comment: @AndersonM.Gomes This is on a normal successful boot:
`UNIT               LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                  
ifup@ens16.service loaded active exited ifup for ens16

1 loaded units listed.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still suspect that two executions of `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables` are running at the same time throughout the boot process. Because of `systemd` normal behavior of starting things concurrently unless advised not to do so, I believe the boot process triggers one script process for the `lo` interface and another for the `ens16` interface. That would result in a concurrent execution of `iptables-restore`, which may cause errors such as `iptables-restore: line 10 failed`. I am unable to supply evidences though.

I am used to managing CentOS and Red Hat systems. Once upon a time, one of such servers failed to initialize `iptables` service on boot because `systemd` was starting `ip6tables` concurrently. That specific error is documented here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1477413

I suggest you to handle concurrency in your script, for example, by using `flock`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/flock /run/.iptables-restore /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Alternatively, you could check the actual value of `${IFACE}` variable before restoring `iptables` rules (reference: [man 5 interfaces](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html)):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${IFACE}" == ens16 ]; then
    /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
fi
```

---

Additionally, if you just want to load `iptables` rules at boot time, I suggest you to use `iptables-persistent` instead:

```
# apt-get install iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent
# mv -v /etc/iptables.up.rules /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# systemctl enable netfilter-persistent.service
# rm -v /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

Comment: I added an `echo "${IFACE}"` to the script and rebooted, and it seems that it is in fact running 3 times, for `--all`, `ens16` and `lo`. So, I'll try your suggestions, and hope that fixes the problem.

Comment: Just to follow up on this 1.5 years later. I've never seen the issue happen since, so I'm confident this answer was the correct solution.